# How to invoke a golang func like"ZRem(key string, members ...string)"?

Tags: go

I want to invoke a method like "ZRem(key string, members ...string)" with key="user_queue" and members=["v1", "v2",... "v50"].

I have tried something like

```
func ZRem(key string, members ...string){
    // do something
}
func main(){
    // do something
    // task_ids is a []string
    ZRem("user_queue", task_ids[0], task_ids[1:]...)
}
```

but receive a compile error.

```
too many arguments in call to ZRem
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 ZRem("user_queue", task_ids...)
```